# Cортировка в массиве

Tags: javascript

Хочу разобрать работу этого кода.

Мне интересно, что означает вернуть 1 и -1?

Это индекс в массиве?

```js
function sortByAge() {
arr.sort(function(a, b){
    
if(a.age > b.age){  //a.age и b.age что это значит? vasya.age и petya.age?
return 1;           // вернуть 1?
}   
      
else{
return -1;          // вернуть -1?
}   
  
})
}

let vasya = { name: "Вася", age: 25 };
let petya = { name: "Петя", age: 30 };
let masha = { name: "Маша", age: 28 };

let arr = [ vasya, petya, masha ];

sortByAge();

alert(arr[0].name); 
alert(arr[1].name); 
alert(arr[2].name);
```

Comment: Это функция-компаратор. Он сравнивает нестандартные типы и возвращает 1 или -1 в зависимости от того, какое значение больше. Это значение используется для выбора того, менять местами элементы при сортировке или нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно документации [arr.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) функция на вход должна получить функцию сравнения, в которой должна быть написана некая логика. Элементы массива сортируются в соответствии с её возвращаемым значением

- Если возвращаемое значение в функции сравнения `compareFunction(a, b)` меньше 0, сортировка поставит a по меньшему индексу, чем b, то есть, a идёт первым.
- Если возвращаемое значение в функции сравнения `compareFunction(a, b)` больше 0, сортировка поставит b по меньшему индексу, чем a.
- Если возвращаемое значение вернёт 0, сортировка оставит a и b неизменными по отношению друг к другу, но отсортирует их по отношению ко всем другим элементам. Обратите внимание: стандарт ECMAscript не гарантирует данное поведение, и ему следуют не все браузеры (например, версии Mozilla по крайней мере, до 2003 года).

Как правило все разработчики пишут "значение меньше 0" как "-1", а "возвращаемое значение больше 0" как "1". Но можно писать даже и -9999999  и 9827376 :)

```js
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a < b) {
    return -2398454;
  }
  if (a > b) {
    return 123478887;
  }
  // a должно быть равным b
  return 0;
}

let numbers = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3];
console.log(numbers.sort(compare));
```

Comment: ой да ладно, все пишут `return a-b`

Comment: это уровень advanced :) мы это в другой вопрос перенесём :)

Comment: В моём случае получается, если a.age > b.age, то вернуть большее значение в других же случаях меньшее?

Comment: Попробовал вместо длинного кода написать return a.age - b.age, не знаю почему, но результат тот же.

Comment: @Человек `если a.age > b.age, то вернуть большее значение в других же случаях меньшее` --- да................`return a.age - b.age, не знаю почему, но результат тот же.` --- потому что, по факту, это тот же код и есть. потому что `a - b` - сортировка по возрастанию `b - a ` - сортировка по убыванию. Например `a - b`. Если `a > b`, то `a - b` вернет положительное число, если `a < b`, то `a - b` вернёт отрицательное число, если равны, то `a - b` вернёт 0. Что соответствует логике написанной в ответе