# Что выполняется в функции, и для чего. Почему значения а и б минусуются

Tags: javascript

Почему значения а и б минусуются?

```js
const arr = [1, 14, 4, 30, 54];
const compareNum = (a, b) => {
    return a - b;
}

let sorted = arr.sort(compareNum);
console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: Читайте документацию к функции sort https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: `compareNum = (a,b)=>a-b;`

Answer (score 2):

Начнём с того, что колбэк функция (если таковую указывать) в методе **[sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)**, определяет порядок сортировки. Чуть подробнее о методе в ссылке выше или **https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1231786/191482**.

Она может возвращать значения больше нуля, меньше нуля или ноль.

Если рассматривать текущий случай:

```
compareNum (a, b) => a - b;
```

Получаем:

- Если `a > b`, то `a - b` вернет положительное число
- Если `a < b`, то `a - b` вернёт отрицательное число
- Если равны, то `a - b` вернёт 0.

Что как раз и соответствует требованиям, которые описаны выше

---

*P.S.* `a - b` - сортировка по возрастанию, `b - a`  - сортировка по убыванию